# Adding additional attributes from array an element in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave

I want to add an array attributes to an existing element dynamically. ++ [array] is not allowed against the element list.
The input payload is

```
{  
  "mainAttribs": [
    {      
      "main": {
        "Id": "123"        
      },
      "extended": {        
        "attributes": {
            "LastName": [
            { 
                "value": "Jone"
            }
          ],         
          "acnumber": [
            {
             "value": "023"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

I need the output json as below. The **LastName** and acnumber is added from config **mapping**

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "attrib": {
        "Id": "123",
        "LastName":"Jone",
        "acnumber": "123"

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying with below code snippe

```
var mappings=[
        {"source": "LastName","target": "RCHName"}, 
        {"source": "acnumber","target": "acnumber"}, 
        ]

var applyMapping = (obj, mappingsDef) -> (
   mappingsDef map (def) -> {    
    "SrcName" : (def.source),
    "TargetName" : (def.target),
    (def.target) : obj.extended.attributes[def.source].value[0]
  }
)
---
{
objects: payload.mainAttribs map ((oAttrib, entityPos) ->
  
  {    
    (attrib: oAttrib.main mapObject {
       ($$): $
   }
   /*
    need to call applyMapping  to add array of attributes
  */
)}
)
}
```

Comment: Not sure if i follow your ask. Can you be a bit more elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var mappings=[
        {"source": "LastName","target": "RCHName"}, 
        {"source": "acnumber","target": "acnumber"}, 
        ]

var applyMapping = (obj, mappingsDef) -> (
   mappingsDef map (def) -> {    
    //"SrcName" : (def.source),
    //"TargetName" : (def.target),
    (def.source) : obj.extended.attributes[def.source].value[0]
  }
)
---
{
objects: payload.mainAttribs map ((oAttrib, entityPos) ->
  
  {    
    (attrib: oAttrib.main mapObject {
       ($$): $}
       ++
       {
        a: {(applyMapping(payload.mainAttribs[0],mappings))}
    }.a
  
)}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script gets the output you asked for:

```
{ objects: payload.mainAttribs map ((item, i1) ->  
    {
        attrib: 
            item.main
            ++
            (item.extended.attributes mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
             (key): value[0].value
            ))
    })
}
```

If you need to replace the names of the keys, you can select the output names from a map where it says `(key):`. Something like `(transformMap[key]):`

Comment: This is so close. Thank you. The output from     (item.extended.attributes mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
             (key): value[0].value
            ))  is expected result.    If I manually do ++ the output from code , required output is  coming. but that snippet is throwing below error You called the function '++' with these arguments: 
  1: Object ({Id: "123"})
  2: Array (org.mule.weave.v2.model.structure.IteratorArraySeq@122eb8b7)

Comment: Hi Temple. Welcome! I had an issue where I had to wrap with parenthesis all the mapObject expression. This was tested on Mule 4.3, I cannot confirm there may be another issue in a previous version. `mapObject` returns an object so, if it doesn't, you probably hit some bug. Besides that, I'm not sure to understand where you say "do ++ the output from code" (which code?) and "snippet" (which one). Maybe it's clearer to modify the original question by adding a `NOTE:` with new examples.

Comment: The code worked. Thanks !! Next step for me to keep the nested source in config..   { objects: payload.mainAttribs map ((item, i1) ->  
    {
        attrib: 
            item.main
            ++
            {
                (mappings map ((aDef) ->    
                 (aDef.target): payload.mainAttribs[0].extended.attributes[aDef.source].value[0]
            
                ))
            }
         
    })
}